# Image reduce website content

Tags: caching, webserver

My site have 2 pages and the 2 pages contain a similar picture. If a user comes to the first page, he downloads the picture and then come to the second page, if I make the website so that the picture is shared between the 2 pages then the user no need to download the picture again?

If I want to put the same picture but different in size on the webpage, is it better to make 2 pictures by using image software editor or using CSS to change the width and the height of the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have answered your question.

if the image is from the same source, and if you have configured the caching on webserver correctly (and if the client has enabled cache), then there are no re-requests sent to view the same resource.

you dont need to create multiple images for different sizes, use html image attributes to show it in the grid dimensions you wish to. 
Exception: if the original image is quite large, and you are not sure if the user will want to view the image, then create smaller image for faster loading. Thumbnails on a photo album is a good example for that. There is a program called re-sizer which accepts a folder and create a new set of images with the required dimensions

Resources below
[Image Resizer](http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/)
[HTTP Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)